# Java Store multiple phone number for one user

Tags: java

Question: Store more than 1 user data with id, name, weight, age, and phone number (can have multiple phone number)

How do I store multiple phone number for one user?

I facing an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Store_User.main(Store_User.java:29). Anyone can solve it?

```
import java.util.List;

public class User {

private int usrid;
private String name;
private double weight;
private int age;
private List<String> Pnum;

public User(int usrid, String name, double weight, int age, List<String> Pnum){
    this.usrid = usrid;
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.age = age;

}

public void setUsrid(int usrid) {
    this.usrid = usrid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public List<String> getPnum() {
    return Pnum;
}

public void setPnum(List<String> pnum) {
    Pnum = pnum;
}

int getUID(){
    return usrid;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Store_User {

public static void main(String[] args) {


User usr1 = new User(1,"Mark", 55.5, 26, Arrays.asList("0140392812", "0123456789"));
User usr2 = new User(2, "Ken", 54.7, 33, Arrays.asList("0129876543"));
User usr3 = new User(3, "Callie", 62.3, 34, Arrays.asList("06123456", "0987654322", "01798654321"));

ArrayList<User> ulist = new ArrayList<User>();

ulist.add(usr1);
ulist.add(usr2);
ulist.add(usr3);


    Iterator itr=ulist.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        User usr = (User)itr.next();
        System.out.println(usr.getUID() +", " + usr.getName() +", " + usr.getAge() +", " + usr.getWeight());


    String out ="";
    for(String number: usr.getPnum()){
        out += number + ";";
    }
    System.out.println(out);

    }


}
```

}
Chat conversation end

Comment: Create and give the User class a collection of phone numbers, such as an ArrayList.

Comment: You need to give much more information. This is extremely vague and unanswerable as is.

Comment: I had created arraylist for user but I have no idea to create another arraylist for phone number and link it to userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Phone numbers are stored as an ArrayList of Strings and are "linked" to the usrId since they are non-static members of the same class, hence each User object will have it's own id and list of numbers. You can access the phone numbers of a user using:

```
usr.getPnum()
```

where usr is an instance of User.java, this will return a `ArrayList<String>` representing the phone numbers, if you want a specific number you can access the list by index like so:

```
usr.getPnum().get(0) //The index in this case is 0
```

---

User.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class User {
    private int usrid;
    private String name;
    private double weight;
    private int age;
    private List<String> Pnum;

    public User(int usrid, String name, double weight, int age, List<String> Pnum){
        this.usrid = usrid;
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.age = age;
        this.Pnum = Pnum;

    }

    public void setUsrid(int usrid) {
        this.usrid = usrid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<String> getPnum() {
        return Pnum;
    }

    public void setPnum(List<String> pnum) {
        Pnum = pnum;
    }

    int getUID(){
        return usrid;
    }
}
```

Store_User.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Store_User {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        User usr1 = new User(1,"Tee Ting Ong", 55.5, 26, Arrays.asList("00000000", "00000000", "00000000"));
        User usr2 = new User(2, "Tee Soon Teh", 54.7, 33, Arrays.asList("00000000", "00000000"));
        User usr3 = new User(3, "Tee Ting Ken", 62.3, 34, Arrays.asList("00000000"));

        ArrayList<User> ulist = new ArrayList<User>();

        ulist.add(usr1);
        ulist.add(usr2);
        ulist.add(usr3);

        Iterator itr=ulist.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            User usr = (User)itr.next();
            System.out.println(usr.getUID() +", " + usr.getName() +", " + usr.getAge() +", " + usr.getWeight());

            //This print out the numbers
            String out = "";
            for(String number : usr.getPnum()){
                out += number + ";";
            }
            System.out.println(out);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is an error as below appear while I running the code.
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Store_User.main"

Comment: Doesn't give any error to me, can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Updated the code at top. I facing an error. Anything wrong for my code?